# Converting float64 to Date

Tags: python, pandas

I am pulling data out of a SQL server using pyodbc.  The issue is I need to pull data from a certain date frame, however; the date comes across in both an incorrect data type and format. Float64 and 90502(5/02/09 is what I would like.)  I am very new to python and far from really even being very good at this and would appreciate any help.

I have tried converting to string, and then strptime but it tells me that the data is in the wrong format.  I have also tried the included code, however it does not seem to do what I would like for it to do, as the data still reads as float64, and does not output as desired.

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
from datetime import datetime
import xlwt
import numpy
date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%m.%d.%Y')


cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    driver='{SQL Server}',
    Server='atlmktsql06',
    Database='Repository',
    trusted_connection='yes')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql = ("""select * FROM dbo.tblAS400_Vcresrv WHERE VRRESV='CCVNQ'""")
df = psql.read_sql_query(sql, cnxn)
cnxn.close()
psql.to_datetime(psql.Series(['VRIN']).astype(str), infer_datetime_format=True, errors='coerce')
a = df.head(60)
print(a)
print(df.dtypes)
df.to_excel(r'C:\PythonCode\Testing.xls')
```

The end result as stated above would be for the data to convert to date, and also read appropriately so I can use the sql statement in python to pull by timeframe.  Currently, VRIN = Float64 and reads as 90502 and I want VRIN = Date 5/02/09. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this:**

```
d = str(int(float(90502)))
print("{0}/{1}/{2}".format(d[1:3],d[3:],str(d[:1]).zfill(2)))
```

**Ouput:**

```
05/02/09
```

You can apply this to your dataframe column and get output in your desired format.

Answer (score 0):

How do you apply the formatting to the dataframe column?

I have a date column that is a int64 with values like '20100331'

I used your answer to code this:

```
d = str(int(float(20100331)))
print("{0}/{1}/{2}".format(d[4:6],d[1:3],str(d[:4])))
```

Which outputs the date correctly as: 03/01/2010

How can I apply this to my column in the dataframe?

Comment: when you define a `dataframe` o reading `csv` files you can assign your `date` column using arguments such as: [`date_parser`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=date_parser) or [`parser_dates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/search.html?q=date_parser)